# In which case that mapView:viewForAnnotation: will be called?

Tags: ios, iphone, annotations, mkmapview, mkmapviewdelegate

Now I want to add a static pin annotation on map in my iOS app.

But I just want to know if the delegate method mapView:viewForAnnotation: will be called.

In the Apple documentation, it is said that

```
 When it needs an annotation view, the map view calls the mapView:viewForAnnotation:    method of its delegate object.
```

I have read several tutorials from Internet and official documentation from Apple.
And I still don't when this method will be called.

Comment: Are you trying to add custom annotation pin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever you call  `addAnnotation` method `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation` gets called. Have look at the screenshot.

[image]

You can find this on **[MKMapView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)**

P.S. Put breakpoints at `addAnnotation` call and `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation` you will see the flow of function call easily.

Comment: Not complete answer, as viewForAnnotation may also be called when Map viewable region changes significantly.  e,g: user zooms in on NYC, then zooms out, then zooms in on London.

Comment: Very helpful!! WAs looking for this for an hour!

Comment: "Whenever you call  addAnnotation method...": No.  The doc screenshot doesn't say that and that's not what happens in practice.  As the OP quoted the docs in the question, viewForAnnotation is called by the map view "When it needs an annotation view".  If the map view is currently displaying the region in which you are adding your annotation, then viewForAnnotation _may_ get called immediately or soon after but there is no guarantee.  As @AmitP also mentioned, viewForAnnotation can also be called multiple times _after_ annotation is already added if region changes.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously `MKMapView` at least will call `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` when it will need to display your `MKAnnotationView` to the screen.