# difference between viewForAnnotation and addAnnotation

Tags: ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I realize that they have different return values.. I suppose I'm asking because I'm trying to "refresh" an annotation's associated view.

Here's the process: I select an annotation and then, via an action sheet, change a property on the annotation, in a different view controller. Say an image in the left callout accessory view.

When I'm finished changing that property, I pop back to my map view controller.  But to see any changes, I have to navigate away from the map view controller.

It seems like the annotation has the changes saved but the annotation's view doesn't reflect those changes.

I'm wondering if it's the way I'm using viewForAnnotation and addAnnotation.

Comment: I'm stil unsure as to the difference but I'm getting the behavior that I want by calling `[self.mapview removeAnnotations:self.mapview.annotations]` before I call either of `viewForAnnotation` or `addAnnotation`.

Comment: I also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442830/in-which-case-that-mapviewviewforannotation-will-be-called).  Is it that simple?  Is viewForAnnotation only called when you call addAnnotation?